# How to make awk work in a while loop

Tags: shell-script, awk, solaris, ksh

```
input.txt:
/usr/dir1/file1
/usr/dir1/file2
/usr/dir2/file4
/usr/dir3/file5

Script:
cat input.txt |while read FILENAME
do
nawk '{print $1}' ${FILENAME} >> output.txt
done

Expected output:
all column1 values of input files

Error:
nawk: can't open file

This works fine when i run it like this
nawk '{print $1}' /usr/dir1/file1 >> output.txt
nawk '{print $1}' /usr/dir1/file2 >> output.txt
nawk '{print $1}' /usr/dir2/file4 >> output.txt
```

I want to be able to run it using a while loop or an if loop with say if $?=0 (using return code).
Any ideas on how to do this?
i am using solaris 5.10, KSH.

Comment: Does `input.txt` have `\r\n` line endings? Try running dos2unix on it.

Comment: @glennjackman no, my input file does not have \r\n. should i include it? how and where?

Comment: Don't do this, please?

Comment: @mikeserv Okay, i will not.

Comment: Try `(set -f; eval "IFS='$(printf \\n\')"; head -n1 $(cat input.txt))` for a pretty quick and dirty approximation. Oh wait, you want the first field, not the first line. So `sed '1s/^/nawk "{print \\$1}" /;$!s/$/ \\/' input.txt | sh`

Comment: @mikeserv i want to use while loop, your solution may work,  but what if i  need to do  a more complex awk statement instead of just  print $1 ?

Comment: @ayton_senna - so do. `sed '1G;1s/\(.*\)\(.\)/IFS="\2"; nawk "$*" \1/;$!s/$/ \\/' <input.txt | sh -s -- '{ print $1 }' 'another awk command' 'and another'` ... where each arg to `sh` will be concatenated into a single argument to `nawk` and separated by newlines. The `while ... read` you do, though, is incredibly inefficient, and calling an outside executable like that inside a shell loop should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @mikeserv What is wrong with my method of using a variable instead of filename? Can someone fix my scripts syntax and let me know how to do it the way i wanted it. I want to keep it simple, all this sed's makes me very tough to interpret whats going on. So please fix my script instead of showing me alternatives. or let me know if what i am trying to do is impossible

Comment: Please cut and paste the exact error messages your script produces.

Comment: @mikeserv and don_crissti you've got good answers there. Why not provide them as Answers so future users can find them easily? (Please)

Answer (score 2):

Piping an input file into a read command is generally a recipe for disaster, it can work in some circumstances, but in many cases it does not. Best to learn a more consistent way of doing this.

Here are a couple of simple alternatives...

```
nawk '{print $1}' $( cat input.txt ) > output.txt
```

or if you want it in a loop...

```
for FILENAME in $( cat input.txt ); do
    nawk '{ print $1 }' $FILENAME >> output.txt
done
```

These approaches have the advantage that you also easily change the phrase

```
$( cat input.txt )
```

.. to something which will throw away comments following a # symbol which gives you ability to add comments to you file lists. e.g.

```
$( cat input.txt | sed 's/#.*//' )
```

**NOTE**: If you need to cater for file paths that contain spaces or tabs then you probably need to skip bash and use a less text/token based scripting language like perl, python, etc..

Comment: `nawk '{print $1}' input.txt > output.txt`...

Comment: In this case the input.txt file contains a list of files for input so it is not the input file and you need to use $( cat input.txt )

Comment: Regarding your note on file names, you could just quote them: `nawk '{ print $1 }' "$FILENAME"`

Comment: Unfortunately the format used in the for loop `$( cat input.txt )` generates space separated values to make the for loop work, so when a file path appears which contains a space you end up with 2 separate strings, which does not work.

Comment: No, to read *lines* of a file, use `while read line; do ...; done < file` (or, yes, `cat file | while read ...` . A  `for x in $(cat file)` loop will read IFS-separated *words* in the file -- it will read lines if you set `IFS=$'\n'`.. Idiomatically, this is the safest to read lines: `while IFS= read -r line`